# Embed PDF with <embed> set to height without scroll bars

Tags: embed, pdf.js

I am using Google Chrome and would like to open a PDF in a Bootstrap Modal (or any container really), where the scroll bars are on the outer element i.e. the modal, and not the PDF.

The problem is that in order to do this one must get the height of the PDF and set the embed to be at least that height. Some ASCII art to demonstrate:

This is not too difficult to accomplish, and here's a [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBQ6K/) that essentially shows this (but instead of a modal we have the jsFiddle window):

```
  /---------------\       where |•| is a scroll bar
  | Modal         |
  |  /--------\   |
  |  | Embed |•|  |
  |  |       | |  |
  |  |       | |  |
  |  \--------/   |
  \---------------/
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
  /----------------\
  | Modal        |•|
  |  /--------\  | |
  |  | Embed  |  | |
  |  |        |  | |
  |  |        |  | |
  \----------------/
```

I could not find on inspection of the `<embed>` DOM node any indication of what dimensions the contained object might have.

As an alternative to the `<embed>` object, could one achieve this with [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)?